# Merge columns cut & cat

Tags: shell

I have file.txt 3 columns.

```
1 A B
2 C D
3 E F
```

I want to add #1&#3 as the end of #2. Result should look like this:

```
1A
2C
3E
1B
2D
3F
```

I am doing this by

```
cut -f 1,2 > tmp1
cut -f 1,3 > tmp2
cat *tmp * > final_file
```

But I am getting repeated lines! If I check the final output with:

`cat * | sort | uniq -d`

there are plenty of repeated lines and there are none in the primary file.

Can anyone suggest other way of doing this? I believe the one I am trying to use is too complex and that's why I am getting such a weird output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pzanoni@vicky:/tmp$ cat file.txt 
1 A B
2 C D
3 E F
pzanoni@vicky:/tmp$ cut -d' ' -f1,2 file.txt > result
pzanoni@vicky:/tmp$ cut -d' ' -f1,3 file.txt >> result
pzanoni@vicky:/tmp$ cat result 
1 A
2 C
3 E
1 B
2 D
3 F
```

I'm using bash

Answer (score 1):

`cat file.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 "\n" $1 $3};'`

Comment: How to awk with tab separated?

Comment: I didn't see that you wanted col1co2 and col1col3. I changed my answer to do that. To answer your question, the reason I chose awk is because by default it takes any whitespace as a delimiter, which makes things like this much easier.

Comment: If you really need them in that order, you can use awk, but in two passes as pzanoni did.  But you don't say whether the order matters or not.

Answer (score 1):

Preserves the order with one pass through the file

```
awk '
    {print $1 $2; pass2 = pass2 sep $1 $3; sep = "\n"} 
    END {print pass2}
' file.txt
```

The reason this (`cat tmp* * > final_file`) is wrong:

- I assume `*tmp` was a typo
- I assume as this point the directory only contains "tmp1" and "tmp2"

Look at how those wildcards will be expanded:

- `tmp*` expands to "tmp1" and "tmp2"
- `*` also expands to "tmp1" and "tmp2"

So your command line becomes `cat tmp1 tmp2 tmp1 tmp2 > final_file` and hence you get  all the duplicated lines.

Comment: It works. No duplicates, but hot to get output tab separated?